# How to set the icon in "Programs and Features" for a Qt application?

Tags: windows, qt, wix, qt5

I have a Qt application deployed via [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org/) and installed via an MSI installer. Now all my app icons are fine, but I don't know how to set this small icon in the list of Programs and Features on Windows.

[image]

My app has this fallback icon which you see for stunnel as well. How can I set the icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use an [icon element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/icon.html) and set the ARPPRODUCTICON for your product.

Inside your MSI Product use the following two lines:

```
<Icon Id="MyIcon" SourceFile="PATH_TO_ICON_FILE.ICO" />
<Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON">MyIcon</Property>
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. Note: the code block needs to be placed inside of `<Product>` and below `<Package>`, otherwise you get an error.